# bsearch and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, linker, bsearch

I'm using a regexp library that calls the standard function `bsearch()`. When using **VS2008**, I must include an extra header for this function to be declared (`<search.h>`).

But when I'm linking, it says that `bsearch` can't be resolved. The MSDN page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0k41tbs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) doesn't indicate any .lib to add for the linking, so I don't know what to do !

I'm compiling for Windows CE (yeah that still exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other folks ran into the issue on `comp.lang.c` some time ago, and the consensus was the function is not supported in the [CE VS package](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2004-08/2782.html).

You'll have to roll your own implementation, which shouldn't be too difficult. Wikipedia is a [good starting point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: The MSDN pages also does not include this function in WinCE in the list of supported [platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk54f3f5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I found an implementatio on SO.